# Counter-example to $(R\cup S)^{*}=R^{*}\cup S^{*}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

We must show if the following equation involving two relations on a set A is true or false:

$(R\cup S)^{*}=R^{*}\cup S^{*}$

Where $R^{*} $ indicates the complement relation of $R$ on the same set.

Is the following counter-example correct?

$A=\{a,b\}$.

$R = \{(a,a),(b,b)\} $ so that $R^{*} = \{(a,b),(b,a)\} $

$S = \{(a,b),(b,a)\} $ so that $S^{*} = \{(a,a),(b,b)\} $

Then  $ R^{*}\cup S^{*}$ is $ A\times A $  while $(R\cup S)^{*} $ is the empty set, so the equality does not hold.

Would this be a correct counter-example?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks valid to me

Comment: Except that $R^{*}\cup S^{*}=A\times A$ and not $R\times S$

Comment: @miracle173 thanks, edited it now

Answer (score 1):

This counter-example is indeed correct, as noted in the comments. In fact, it is easier to see that the statement should not hold in general thanks to De Morgan's laws:

$$\left( \bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{I}} A_i \right)^* = \bigcap_{i \in \mathcal{I}} A_i^*$$